# POWERBI count How many student in different course

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have table contain
name     course     attendance

I want count how many student in different course

Output I want = 3 student
because Ahmad have two different course

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBU6O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

test this measure:

```
Result =
COUNTROWS ( SUMMARIZE ( TableName, TableName[name], TableName[course name] ) )
```

You can also add the 3rd column:

Alternative Solution :

```
Result =
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE (
        TableName,
        TableName[name],
        TableName[course name],
        TableName[attendence]
    )
)
```

If we test them, the result is the same:

[image: JHK]

Answer (score 0):

```
SUMX(
    VALUES(tbl[course name])
    ,CALCULATE(
         COUNTROWS(VALUES(tbl[name]))
    )
)
```